# TypeError: flow_from_directory() got an unexpected keyword argument 'train_data_dir'

Tags: python-3.x, keras, directory, arguments, keyword

I need help please.

I try to run this code and I have this error:

> TypeError: flow_from_directory() got an unexpected keyword argument 'train_data_dir'

Has any one had this problem and have the right solution?

Thanks

```
train_datagenerator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    validation_split=0.2)
train_generator = train_datagenerator.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir = '.\\Images\\data',
    target_size=(image_size, image_size), 
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE_TRAINING,
    class_mode='categorical', subset='training') 
validation_generator = train_datagenerator.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir = '.\\Images\\data', 
    target_size=(image_size, image_size), 
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE_TRAINING,
    class_mode='categorical', subset='validation')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no train_data_dir argument in flow_from_directory method. Replace train_data_dir with directory and it should work. Refer https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/

```
train_datagenerator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    validation_split=0.2)
train_generator = train_datagenerator.flow_from_directory(
    directory = '.\\Images\\data',
    target_size=(image_size, image_size), 
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE_TRAINING,
    class_mode='categorical', subset='training')
```